# Removing reference

Tags: c++, reference

I'd like to know how to cancel reference. For example:
I have

```
class Student {...};
```

then I create object:

```
Student Caroline;
```

and later i make reference:

```
Student &princess = Caroline;
```

And from now on I can use princess or Caroline to see my object, but  I decide na call Her no longer princess and I want to remove this reference: how to do it? I know I can't change reference, but I was told it can't be called of.
Thx in advance for help

Answer (score 2):

Impossible (as far as I know). Once a reference points to an object there's no changing it.

An alternative is pointers:

```
Student *princess = &Caroline;
princess->name = "Still Caroline";
princess = &Sarah;
princess->name = "Still Sarah";
```